# Remove rows having same value in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I'm trying to drop rows based on all columns having exact same value. Here's an example to help understand the idea.

Input:

```
index  A  B  C  D  E  F ....
 0     1  2  3  1  3  4
 1     2  2  2  2  2  2
 2     5  5  5  5  5  5 
 3     7  7  6  7  7  7
```

Output:

```
index  A  B  C  D  E  F ....
 0     1  2  3  1  3  4
 3     7  7  6  7  7  7
```

There can be many columns here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An efficient way of doing this with numeric DataFrames is to use the standard deviation (which will be 0 only if all values are the same):

```
df[df.std(axis=1) > 0]
Out: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  3  1  3  4
3  7  7  6  7  7  7
```

As [tgrandje](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703250/remove-rows-having-same-value-in-all-columns/47703346?noredirect=1#comment134769339_47703346) points out, due to floating point inaccuracy the standard deviation may not be exactly zero. You can instead use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for a more robust approach:

```
df[~np.isclose(df.std(axis=1), 0)]
```

which results in the same answer.

Timings with 40k rows:

```
%timeit df[df.std(axis=1) > 0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop

%timeit df[df.nunique(1) > 1]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.62 s per loop
```

Comment: This is working fine, but one needs to proceed with caution regarding the standard deviation's precision (usually `numpy.float64`). I ended up in some cases with std = 4e-15, which would result in wrong selection.

Comment: @tgrandje You are correct. I've added an update for that issue.

Comment: You might want to re-check/update those statistics, they seem obsolete; first timeit gives me 1.06ms; the second (with `nunique`) 1.1ms; using the `np.isclose(df.std(axis=1), 0)` from your last update gives me 1.05ms. **If you increase the number of rows**, `nunique` is way bellow `np.isclose(df.std(axis=1), 0)`'s performance whether working with integers or floats (respectively 1.98s vs 22.4ms on my machine with 40k rows of float64).

Comment: @tgrandje That's interesting. I still get a much worse performance on `nunique`: https://imgur.com/RBPw5rJ

Answer (score 5):

Using `nunique`

```
df=df[df.nunique(1)>1]
df
Out[286]: 
       A  B  C  D  E  F
index                  
0      1  2  3  1  3  4
3      7  7  6  7  7  7
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another efficient (well not that fast as @ayhan's solution) way:

```
In [17]: df[~df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)]
Out[17]:
       A  B  C  D  E  F
index
0      1  2  3  1  3  4
3      7  7  6  7  7  7
```

Timing for 40.000 rows DF:

```
In [19]: df.shape
Out[19]: (40000, 6)

In [20]: %timeit df[df.std(axis=1) > 0]
5.62 ms ± 162 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit df[df.nunique(1)>1]
9.87 s ± 104 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [23]: %timeit df[~df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)]
13 ms ± 86.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```